# Finding nested element inside attribute?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have html file which contains below content:

```
<html>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="<custom:test code="key"  />">
    </div>
</html>
```

Java Program:

```
String input = readFileAsString(filePath);
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input);

Elements messageEls = doc.select("custom|test");
```

I see messageEls as empty. How can i find elements which nested under attributes ?

Comment: you can use jsoup but it will return "<custom:test code="
as value.
"<custom:test code="

Comment: Refer to this document: https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html Your query inside select method should of type Selector. So try using this doc.select([value="<custom:test"])